# Unmanaged custom object tab already exists, package upgrade cannot create another tab

Tags: managed-package, deployment

I am trying to upgrade managed package in salesforce and I got the following error:

**Type:** Installed Package

**Error:**
(ObjectA__c) Unmanaged custom object tab already exists, package upgrade cannot create another tab, Details: ObjectA__c: Unmanaged custom object tab already exists, package upgrade cannot create another tab

What could be the rootcause for this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is just what the error message says, although it takes a bit of unpacking to be clear.  The package owns a custom object, and at the time you originally installed it, did not include a Custom Tab for that object. Your org created a Custom Tab for it at some point.

A newer package version is now including a Custom Tab for that same object. You won’t be able to install that version until you remove your own Custom Tab, at which point you can install the new package version and use the Custom Tab it provides.

Comment: Thanks @David it worked. I have deleted existing tab and new version of managed package recreated the tab. I appreciate your response to my question.